# Get the Category Name in WordPress - efficient or "bad" code?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

This is a question that is more about code best practices:

```
$cat_name = get_the_category()[0]->name;
```

Instead of doing this with a few vars, in a few steps:

```
$cat = get_the_category();
$cat_name = $cat[0]->name;
```

Is this considered bad practice? or is it in any way problematic? if so why? Again, my question is about the code, not the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends on whether you have php set to display notices, and whether you care about undefined offset notices. Here's the issue (IMO). Check out the beginning of the function:

```
function get_the_category( $id = false ) {
    $categories = get_the_terms( $id, 'category' );
    if ( ! $categories || is_wp_error( $categories ) )
        $categories = array();
```

You can see that if there are no categories or an error "happens", the method returns an empty array. Doing a quick test...

```
<?php

$categories = array();

echo $categories[0]->name;
```

We get

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in test.php on line 5

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test.php on line 5
```

See the problem?

Probably best to:

```
$cat = get_the_category();
if ($cat)
{
    $cat_name = $cat[0]->name;
}
```

Comment: I see. Than you for your answer @typeoneerror. So it is not a good idea to try and access an element in an array before knowing if there are any element in it in the first place. That does make sense!